# My Lua maze builder that is braiding

Tags: lua, maze

I am building a Lua script that generates a maze using a version of the Recursive Backtracker implemented with a stack rather than recursion. Presently the maze is coming out braided and I can't seem to figure out where in my logic this is happening.  The function below takes in x and y as a starting point for generating the maze which is a 2d structure (table of tables):

```
local function buildMazeInternal(x,y,maze)

    local stack = {}
    local directions = {'North','East','South','West'}

    table.insert(stack,{x=x,y=y})

    while #stack > 0 do
        local index = 1
        local nextX = x
        local nextY = y
        local braid = false 

        for i = #directions, 2, -1 do -- backwards
            local r = calc:Roll(1,i) -- select a random number between 1 and i
            directions[i], directions[r] = directions[r], directions[i] -- swap the randomly selected item to position i
        end

        while index <= #directions and nextX == x and nextY == y do
            if directions[index] == 'North' and y > 1 and not maze[y-1][x].Visited then
                maze[y][x].North = true
                maze[y-1][x].South = true
                nextY = y-1
            elseif directions[index] == 'East' and x < width and not maze[y][x+1].Visited then
                maze[y][x].East = true
                maze[y][x+1].West = true
                nextX = x+1
            elseif directions[index] == 'South' and y < height and not maze[y+1][x].Visited then
                maze[y][x].South = true
                maze[y+1][x].North = true
                nextY = y+1
            elseif directions[index] == 'West' and x > 1 and not maze[y][x-1].Visited then
                maze[y][x].West = true
                maze[y][x-1].East = true
                nextX = x-1
            else
                index = index + 1
            end
        end

        if nextX ~= x or nextY ~= y then
            x = nextX
            y = nextY
            maze[y][x].Visited = true
            table.insert(stack,{x=x,y=y})
        else    
            x = stack[#stack].x
            y = stack[#stack].y
            table.remove(stack)
        end
    end
end
```

I know I'm overlooking something but I can't seem to nail it down.  Note that the `calc:Roll(1,100)` method is a .net method in my app used to simulate rolling dice, in this case 1 * 100 sided die, it could be replaced with a call to `math.Random(1,100)` for use outside of my application.

Comment: It means that there are cul-de-sacs in the maze or paths that either do not deadend or solve the maze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after posting on Reddit.  I wasn't setting the initial cell to visited allowing it to be passed through twice.  The correction was to add `maze[y][x].Visited = true` immediately before `table.insert(stack,{x=x,y=y})`.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least one problem. When you go "want to go up", you check whether the "cell which is up" was visited, and if it is, you "skip" going up.

This does not seem to be correct IMHO. If you want to go up, but the cell which is "up" from the current cell was visited **but has a "down" exit**, you should still be able to go up (instead of skipping because it is visited).

The same applies to the other directions.

That's all I got.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  I don't ever want to enter a previously visited cell because that will create a cul-de-sac.  So if my next direction is North and the cell to the North has already been visited, I shouldn't go North.  I move on to the next possible direction.

Comment: Ok you are mixing up things up. "Filling up one cell in one direction" and "choosing which cell to treat next" are two separate things. What I am saying is that "you are skipping filling some cells erroneously". It can also happen that you are also "choosing which cell to go next" erroneously, but I didn't enter into that on my answer.

Comment: I don't see where this condition is occurring.  When the decision is made to go north, the status of the cell to the north has already been checked to be not visited.  A cell can only have one or two exits.  The first exit is determined when first visiting the cell and the second when the next cell is determined.  I may still be misunderstanding the issue you are pointing out.